# :pseudo element animation doesn't work properly in IE11

Tags: css, html

I've develop a tooltip using `:pseudo element` and `HTML5 data-attri`. But my animation not working properly in IE11. the arrow icon appear first in IE11 and the tooltip box appear just a few seconds later.

Please have a look at [**JSIBN Link**](http://jsbin.com/dusoqoyoma/1/edit).

I am using this CSS code.

```
li:after{
    content:attr(data-tip);
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    left:5.3em;
    background: #2989d8; 
    border-radius:5px; 
    color:#ffffff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:5px;
}
li:before,
li:after {
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity ease-in .50s;
}
```

and HTML Code is

```
<ul>
    <li class="arrow_box" data-tip="I am Advanced Tooltip">Home</li>
    <li data-tip="I am Tooltip">About US</li>
    <li data-tip="I am Tooltip">Products</li>
    <li data-tip="I am Tooltip">Contact Us</li>
    <li data-tip="I am Tooltip">Upcoming Feature</li>
    <li data-tip="I am Tooltip">New Events</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "The arrow icon appear first in IE11 and the tooltip box appear just a few seconds later." - Same for Chrome

Comment: @Jonathan haven't checked for chrome. it common sense if it not working on stupid IE how could you imagine it will work on chrome which is more intelligent than IE.

Comment: For me: it's working fine in IE11, chrome and firefox ...

Comment: thanks all! for your valuable inputs. Nice to see you  @C-link Nepal.

Comment: @KheemaPandey nice to see you as well.

Comment: @KheemaPandey Could you please be specific what is the key problem?

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal the problem was on :hover arrow appear a few seconds earlier. but this seems solves now so I am closing this question because this question doesn't going to help anyone.

Comment: But I see its fine..any good luck with your work..

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsbin.com/pokabuwajo/1/

change

```
li:hover:before {
  ..
}
```

to

```
li:before {
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right:8px solid #2989d8;
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:6px;
  left:4.2em;
  width:10px;
}
```